# Как зациклить произведение звуковых файлов?

Tags: c#, winforms, аудио

В программе имеются 3 песни, как сделать так, чтобы по завершению одного музыкального файла, проигрывался следующий, и так до тех пор, пока программа не завершит свою работу

```
  private void enter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)// Вход
    {
        SoundPlayer splay = new SoundPlayer(@"c:\music.play_.wav");
        splay.Play();
        string[] file = DownloadFileFromServer("http://", "members");
        for (int i = 0; i < file.Length; i++)
        {              
                if (enter_login.Text == file[i]&& enter_password.Text==file[i+1])
                {
                chat_panel.Visible = true;
                login_text.Text = enter_login.Text;                       
                password_text.Text = enter_password.Text;                                   
                nickname = enter_login.Text;                             
                }
        }        
        if (chat_panel.Visible == false)
            MessageBox.Show("Неверный логин или пароль");           
    }к
```

Comment: Приведите свой код: с помощью чего воспроизводится музыка.

Comment: Класс `SoundPlayer` - это что? Windows Media Player или что-то иное?

Comment: System.Media это

Comment: Думается мне, вот один из вариантов ответа на ваш вопрос: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tbx06asw(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно воспроизводить звуковые файлы синхронно, в бесконечном цикле, в отдельном потоке (таске).

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    // Здесь загрузка ваших файлов
    var files = new string[] {
        @"C:\Windows\Media\Alarm01.wav",
        @"C:\Windows\Media\Alarm02.wav",
        @"C:\Windows\Media\Alarm03.wav" };

    var player = new SoundPlayer();

    while (true)
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            player.SoundLocation = file;
            player.PlaySync();
        }
    }
}, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

Обратите внимание на опцию `LongRunning` - желательно её указать, так как задача будет выполняться долго.

Comment: А ведь есть вроде асинхронный режим работы плеера, если ничего не путаю.

Comment: @BlackWitcher - Есть асинхронный. Но нет события окончания воспроизведения трека. Поэтому как включать следующую композицию? Разве что уничтожать плеер после каждого трека и по событию `Disposed` создавать новый. Имхо, это сложнее.

Comment: А там у него есть state, вот его нужно смотреть. На английском Stackowerflow есть [пример](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20024126/6935496).

Comment: @BlackWitcher - Там пример для `MediaPlayer`. Тут речь о примитивном `SoundPlayer`, который только wav-файлы воспроизводит.

Comment: Виноват, действительно, так. А про отдельный таск вы уже дали ответ, который плюсанул уже давно.